# How to retrieve data from URL and parse the data in my page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, html

I wish to retrieve data from website using AngularJS. Actually, my task is to implement a page  for "shipping cart" . but, for resource they given one URL which is having one webpage with the details of some product. so, I have to retrieve data from that web page to my page and i have to implement "shipping cart" for that data.. could you please help me to find out exact figure in my page.. thanks in advance.

Comment: So basically you want to scrap data from the given website and push into your database

Comment: Ok, But How i can parse the data from the webpage?That is my primary question..!!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the use of the $http service, you can find a description [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).